# java - DateFormat format string for epoch

Tags: java, date-format

Suppose I have a function like the one below (for example purposes):

```
String convertDateFormat(String inputFormat, String outputFormat, String dateString) throws Exception {
    DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
    DateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);
    return outputDateFormat.format(inputDateFormat.parse(dateString));
}
```

What would I need to set `outputFormat` to, in order to get a Unix epoch string as output (assuming `dateString` is in the format given by `inputFormat`)?

I noticed that the unix command line has a format string for epoch (`date +%s`), but I couldn't find an equivalent in Java.

---

EDIT: What is needed here is 1) a function which takes a format string as input and returns the date as per the format 2) there should be a format string that will output the date as the unix epoch.

Is there a way to do this with `DateFormat`?

Comment: Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() will give time matching the unix timestamp. Is this what you are looking?

Comment: Don't use Calendar.  A Date already has a [getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) method.  There is no need for any `outputDateFormat` whatsoever.

Comment: I know about the getTime() method of date - I was just curious if it was possible to do it with DateFormat as well. For example, say I had a small program where I have 3 text fields for each of those parameters - The input format, the output format and the input date.

Comment: Basically, if I ask the user to specify what the output format should be, via something like a text box - what would he have to enter, to get the epoch as output?